# Resource image not showing WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have 3 .png pictures and I would like to add them on a grid ( to put it simply )
2 of my pictures are shown corretly but the firts isn't, and I don't know why:

Here's my app.xaml lines for all 3 pictures:

```
    <BitmapImage x:Key="EditIcon" UriSource="Ressources\EdtIcon.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="DeleteIcon" UriSource="Ressources\DltIcon.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="InterroIcon" UriSource="Ressources\InterroIcon.png"/>
```

Here's the way I put the 3 of them into the grid:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="top"  Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MouseLeftButtonUp="ButtonComparerCorrection_Click">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding InterroIcon}"/>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>

<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MouseLeftButtonUp="ButtonDeleteRow_Click">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding DeleteIcon}"/>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>

<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="top"  Margin="1,0,0,1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MouseLeftButtonUp="ButtonEditRow_Click">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding EditIcon}"/>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The only image that doesn't show up is the first one: InterroIcon
I checked the name of the png file and it's also InterroIcon

After checking on internet, I verified and the generation action is 'Resource', and the copy is set on 'if newer', usually that's what fixes the problems but not in my case

What could be the cause of this problem ?

Thank you for taking your time

Comment: Also all the pictures are on the same folder, and the "Horizontal Alignment " set to center while the others are on stretch isn't the cause

Comment: I am very confused. InterroIcon is a key for a resource. I would expect `{StaticResource InterroIcon}`, not `{Binding InterroIcon}`. if binding works, then there is a different InterroIcon somewhere

Comment: using StaticResource instead of Binding worked,

I know very little in XAML but in that case if I don't have duplicate files for the other 2 pictures how is the binding working for them ?

Comment: " how is the binding working for them" - that is what *I'm asking*. it is not a binding to resource, but to some property. make a search in project

Comment: I had another class returning the bitmap images of edit and delete icons, I'm taking back the project and not the only one on it, so I guess this must be someone else's work

Edit: this is used to make the pictures visible or not depending on certain conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{Binding InterroIcon}` will work if there is `InterroIcon` property in DataContext, compatible with `ImageSource` type.

Since you have declared image resources, it makes more sense to use them (no binding errors, and Image resources don't belong to DataContext in MVVM architecture):

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource InterroIcon}"/>

<ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource DeleteIcon}"/>

<ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource EditIcon}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !